# Why is the ratio of the number of terms needed to achieve successive integer values in the harmonic series approximately $e$?

Tags: exponential-function, harmonic-numbers

Consider the harmonic series:
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5} + \cdots .$$

It takes $1$ term to achieve a partial sum of $1$, since $1$ is the first number.

It takes $4$ terms to achieve a partial sum of $2$: 
$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} = 2.08\bar{3}$ is the first partial sum of value at least $2$.

To get to $3$ it takes $11$ terms.
To get to $4$ it takes $31$ terms.
To get to $5$ it takes $83$ terms.

If you consider this equation: $x_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ and replace $x$ with any natural number then: ${(x+1)}_{n*e}$

I might not be wording this correctly, but I want to know whether and how it can be shown mathematically why $e$ appears to show up in the ratio of the numbers of terms required for partial sums that take on successive integer values.

**More examples**

The first partial sum in the harmonic series larger than $15$ is

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1835421} > 15$$

The first partial sum larger than 16 is

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{4989191} > 16$$

Note that $\frac{4989191}{1835421}$ is an approximation of $e$.

I've calculated the first five of the quotients of the iterations needed to reach partial sums of integers:

$\frac{4}{1}$

$\frac{11}{4}$

$\frac{31}{11}$

$\frac{83}{31}$

$\frac{227}{83}$

Comment: So, basically your question is the following: If $x_n$ is the number of terms in the partial sum of the harmonic series that exceeds $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for the first time, then is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=e$? Is that correct?

Comment: No, $n$ is the number of terms in the partial sum of the harmonic series that exceeds $x$ for the first time, and $\frac{{x+1}_{n_1}}{x_{n_2}}=e$ approximately.

Comment: Just read my reformulation once carefully, I think you will see it is the same. The reason I have used notation $x_n$ is to treat it like a sequence and then have some insight about it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, sorry I was just confused since you switched the variables from my original question.

Comment: Essentially I am wondering why it equals $e$ and if somebody can show me the math that calculates $e$, since I don't see why this formula should make approximations of $e$.

Comment: Yes, this is something interesting indeed. I am also trying to see how we can get some insight about this phenomenon.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A002387.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $n$th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)
$$H_n := 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$$
satisfies
$$H_n = \log n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12 n^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right),$$
where $$\gamma = 0.5772156649\ldots$$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant (for a little more about this asymptotic approximation, see [this subsection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Relation_to_the_zeta_function) of that article).
Even for reasonably small $n$, the $\log n$ term dominates the terms in negative powers of $n$. Those terms are hence negligible for our purposes, and we have
$$H_n \approx \log n + \gamma.$$
So, rearranging gives that the number $n_N$ of terms of the harmonic series needed to achieve a sum $H_n \geq N$ is
$$n_N \approx \exp(N - \gamma).$$

The estimates this expression furnishes for the values $N$ mentioned in the question are (rounding the values in the last column to the nearest $10^{-3}$):
\begin{array}{ccc}
N & n_N & \exp(N - \gamma)\\
\hline
2 & 4 & 4.148 \\
3 & 11 & 11.277 \\
4 & 31 & 30.655 \\
5 & 83 & 83.327 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
15 & 1835421 & 1835420.815 \\
16 & 4989191 & 4989191.048\\
\end{array}
As we can see, this estimate produces good values even for very small values of $N$. (Already for $N = 2$, we need $n_N = 4$ terms, and the dominant correction term here only contributes $\frac{1}{2(4)} = \frac{1}{8}$.) It's probably not hard to write down very good bounds on the error of this estimate (and hence justify discarding the remaining terms in the above expansion), but I don't know offhand what they are.

So, even for reasonably small $N$, the ratio of the number $n_{N + 1}$ of terms of the harmonic series needed to achieve a sum $N + 1$ to the number $n_N$ of terms needed for a sum $N$ is
$$\frac{n_{N + 1}}{n_N} \approx \frac{\exp((N + 1) - \gamma)}{\exp(N - \gamma)} = \exp(1) = e,$$
as claimed. It should be easy to use the error estimates mentioned above to show that the limit of this ratio as $N \to \infty$ is indeed $e$ as claimed.

Note by the way that the above argument doesn't use that $N$ is an integer, and so we can just as well use our estimate for noninteger $N$. For example, for $N = 2 \pi$ we need $301$ terms, and the formula gives the estimate $\exp(2 \pi - \gamma) = 300.656\ldots .$

Comment: How do you turn $Hn≈logn+γ$ into $nN≈exp(N−γ)$ ? That's the only part I don't understand. I am in first year high school, so could you explain that part in a way that would be more clear for me?

Comment: It's more or less renaming and solving: If we want to find the approximate number of terms needed for a sum $\geq N$, we're looking for a number $n$ that in particular satisfies $H_n \approx N$. I call the number of terms needed to make a sum $\geq N$ by the name $n_N$, since the answer uses this quantity for more than one value of $N$. Anyway, we replace $H_n$ with $N$ and $n$ with $n_N$ in our formula, giving $N \approx \log n_N + \gamma$, and solving for $n_N$ in this approximation gives $\log n_N = N - \gamma$ and then $n_N = \exp(N - \gamma)$. Very nice observation, by the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_{n}-1}\lt n$$ and $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}\gt n.$$ If for some $N$, $$\frac{1}{x_n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N}\ge 1,$$ then $x_{n+1}\le N$ and if for some $M$, $$\frac{1}{x_n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{M}\lt 1-\frac{1}{x_n},$$ then $x_{n+1}\gt M$. Now it is easy to see that if $$
\int_{x_n+1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{x}dx\ge1\Rightarrow N\ge-1+e(x_n+1)=ex_n+e-1,$$then $\frac{1}{x_n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N}\ge 1$, so $$x_{n+1}\le ex_n+e,$$ and if $$\int_{x_n}^{M}\frac{1}{x}dx\lt1-\frac{1}{x_n}\Rightarrow M\lt e^{1-\frac{1}{x_n}}x_n,$$then $\frac{1}{x_n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{M}\lt 1-\frac{1}{x_n},$so $$x_{n+1}\ge e^{1-\frac{1}{x_n}}x_n -1.$$ These bounds show that, indeed, $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\rightarrow e.$$